# How to cluster the retrieved URL related to my query using any clustering algorithm

Tags: java

How should I give my input to a clustering algorithm?
I need to cluster the related URL based on their association and those URL's are retrieved by which are related to my query using a search engine and I need  to group them. I want to do this with Java.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the involved clusting algorithms and APIs you want to use.

Comment: I Do use K means clustering algorithm but I dono how to give my retrievd URL as an input to that algorithm.And I use google search engine

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have any code, then please add it to the question.

Comment: I tried Upto fetching query from user passing it to a dictionary and finding the context of it,Later passing it to the search engine that fetches the related url ...now i need to group them based on similarity existng among those corpus...I dono how to do that?? Please help me

Comment: Please someone help me .. i need working k means clustering code in java that take dataset consisting of URL as an input